# NextJS React Firestore Cannot read properties on first load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a React NextJS project with Firebase v9 with THREE.JS. I am trying to load the following:

```
 const texture = useTexture(floorDoc.url)
```

The issue I am facing is on the first load. I get an error in my console saying, "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')," a common error for an undefined element, even though it is defined in my Firestore DB.

If I replace (floorDoc.url) with a general website string then reload and re-add (floorDoc.url) back into my code it reads the correct Firestore document perfectly and works as intended so I am lost as to why it cant fetch on the first request.

Here is my code:

```
export default function FloorComponent({ postRef }) {
  const floorRef = postRef.collection('assets').doc('floor');
  const [floorDoc] = useDocumentData(floorRef);

  const [ref] = usePlane(() => ({
    rotation: [-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0],
  }));
  const texture = useTexture(floorDoc.url)

  return (
    <mesh rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
      <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[100, 100]} />
      <meshBasicMaterial map={texture}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a conditional return?

```
return texture ? (
    <mesh rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
      <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[100, 100]} />
      <meshBasicMaterial map={texture}
      />
    </mesh>
    ) : 'Some fallback...' 
`
```

Comment: I have tried that and had no luck getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you should do this server side, export following in the page you want this,

```html
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const floorRef = await postRef.collection('assets').doc('floor')
    return {
        props: {
            floorRef
        }
      }
}
```

and you will find floorRef in props of the component

```html
export default function FloorComponent({ postRef, floorRef }) {
  const [floorDoc] = useDocumentData(floorRef);

  const [ref] = usePlane(() => ({
    rotation: [-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0],
  }));
  const texture = useTexture(floorDoc.url)

  return (
    <mesh rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
      <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[100, 100]} />
      <meshBasicMaterial map={texture}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
}
```

Comment: I can't do this because I am using getStaticPaths since the component is a general template. Is there no way to pull data from a subcollection of a static path?

Comment: try to do same thing inside getStaticProps instead of getServerSideProps and then pass the props to the component